Are there physical cases where we deliberately randomise the events?
There are random events like flipping a coin to get head or tail, or , rolling a dice to get a number, or ,drawing a ace of spades from a deck of cards randomly etc. In quantum mechanics entangled particles spin is measured assuming randomness in orientation of spin.(Of course we can assign probability to all such events.)
My question is : Are there physical cases where we deliberately ignore the actors and assume the events to be random in nature ? ( For example , some religious texts believe lightening occurs because of actors like God of lightening, and we as scientists choose to ignore any such actor and believe that lightening is random in nature. )
Do we deliberately try to randomise events to hide the actors?
Edit: Jo Wheler asked for more examples to clarify. Because it is my question I hardly have clear answer but I will try. Origin of Universe had random beginnings where as religious texts say actors like God were involved. (Random here means driven purely by chance) . Another example would be gene mutation. I and some other experts like Deepak Chopra feel that mutation is guided by consciousness. Another example would be mosquitos biting people. It may appear random but in actuality consciousness or karma is playing the role and we are hiding the actors involved.

An actor is a human or at least a living being in the role of an agent. Science like physics does not use the concept of an actor. According to quantum mechanics many events on the quantum scale do not even have a cause. – Hence: Whom do you mean by “we” in your last sentence? – Please give an example for what you call “deliberately try to randomise events to hide the actors”.

We know plenty about how lightning works and why it forms. If we just accepted assertions that a deity did it, we wouldn't have investigated further, and wouldn't know all the things about it that we know now. We don't accept people saying God did it because we don't have the evidence to back up that claim, and different people are all saying different gods did different things for different reasons. Scientists explaining lightning are just doing science, not conspiring to lie about gods (which many scientists themselves believe in).

By "randomize [sth]," do you mean "intepret [sth] to be random in nature," or "choose [sth] randomly"? Several answers seem to assume you mean the latter (which is the common usage), but I think you mean the former.

We try to generate random numbers for a wide variety of calculations including efforts to simulate natural systems. Look up any formal paper on random number generators. Truly random number generators don't exist. Humans only generate pseudo-random numbers. Encryption and decryption algorithms, for example, depend on robust random number generation.

You seem to be using the verb "randomize" in an unusual way. Usually we mean to randomize an object is to select it from a probability distribution (or, in reality, from some mechanical system that is supposed to instantiate the probability distribution). For example, in the role-playing game Dungeons and Dragons we "randomize" ability scores by rolling a 6-sided die 5 times and adding up the results. You seem to be using it to mean "model [an event] as random".
Further, all of your examples are presented as modeling the event in bad faith! Which adds another dimension.

Assuming "randomness" (by which you seem to mean the absence of an intentional actor or some other organizing force, which is not the standard meaning) is the null hypothesis against which more substantive proposals are tested. In this sense, it is "deliberate", deliberately unassuming. Alternative hypotheses from your examples, the god of lightning, consciousness causing mutations, etc., simply perform worse than the null, and hence are discarded. In plain words, they are too outlandish to be taken seriously without some very compelling evidence.

Many courts randomize (at least from the perspective of an outside observer) the assignment of a judge or judges to a case. This is to avoid the possibility of "judge shopping."
The judicial system also randomizes, to an extent, the selection of jurors. This is to avoid the parties from being able to place too heavy a weight on the scales in their favour.
In executions by firing squad, it is sometimes the practice to assign randomly to one or more of the members a blank or dummy cartridge, for the purpose of diffusion of responsibility.

The example you provide in your question is not a circumstance of people "deliberately try[ing] to randomise" an event. Lightning has a cause. The cause that we ascribe to lightning has no bearing on whether it is in fact random or not, or caused by God or not. We cannot "try to randomise" lightning.

I really like your firing squad example. It seems to capture the essence of this question, in which causation clearly puts the responsibility on a single individual, but our intentional ignorance of the probabilistic result distributes the blame across the group. The other examples differ because the probabilistic choice is made before any action is taken, making the chain of causation still clear.

Randomness is very helpful in many algorithms.  The utility of randomness (over, say arbitrary input) in these cases is usually that random input is guaranteed by definition not to correlate with other parts of the problem, leading one to very likely end up in an "average case" situation, rather than a "worst case" situation.  An example is quick sort which has provably nice properties "most of the time" specifically because of the random choice of pivot.  OTOH, if one were to arbitrarily choose a pivot instead of randomly - e.g., "the first value in the list" as a pivot, then lists that are already sorted would sort extremely slowly, which would be unfortunate.
Another example in CS is that AI models such as LLM, GAN and Diffusion models all require a source of randomness, else they would be deterministic in the sense of always producing the same output for the same input.

No, for explaining any phenomena, neither science nor philosophy allows to discard a known cause or agent and to replace it with random. This approach would have no benefit.
The opposite is very much true, religion, spiritualism, superstitions and non-rational beliefs all try to assign an agent to events that would otherwise seem random or arbitrary.
In psychology several biases and effects are known that push humans without training to do so. Attributing an agents will to some event can create the illusion of partial control (by praying or sacrificing virgins) or reduce stress. Also in the form of religion it allows to steer the gullible masses for political or economic purposes. In psychology there are also various perception biases such as selective perception which make humans think a random event is not random. This is also exploited in Casinos where possible.
In the history of humanity, science and philosophy often had to revert such false attributions of random or arbitrary events to various ghosts, angels, demons, spirits, gods, secret government agencies, energy fields and so on. But this is a reversal of a prior mistaken attribution by people who often lived hundreds of years ago and had an education that would not even suffice to pass high school today.
Note technically science and Philo do not explain things with random as a cause, often the explanation is based on natural laws being negligibly random only. Maybe the OP rather means "unguided" or "intention-less" causes as opposed to mathematical random.

No, for explaining any phenomena, neither science nor philosophy allows to discard a known cause or agent and to replace it with random - I'm not sure. Many things may have deterministic, but pragmatically unknowable behavior, and could be productively modeled as random. For example, chaotic events. Motion of fluids or large numbers of particles. Behavior of groups of people such as in voting, or economic.

I already used a cautious phrasing. There are also explanations without deterministic or precise models, but the OP is asking specifically about things thought to be caused by gods and such before. I never heard of a theology of fluid dynamics. Sciences certainly don't try hard to use random when a deterministic model serves the purpose sufficiently. Only when deterministic models fail would other models be used.
